# Match and replace placeholders in a string

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I am working on a small CMS which takes a developer `stdClass` object and processes it accordingly. The `stdClass` contains arrays and other objects. One of these objects is a variables object. There maybe lots of variables objects.

I will just explain this instead of showing the code to make it less confusing. The developer specifies a variable and a set of values that may go into that variable. The values that the user specifies maybe multidimensional arrays. This is an example of how the variables object is created:

```
//Add variable1
$variable = $variables[] = new stdClass;
$variable->name = 'var1'; $variable->generator = 'function'; $variable->value = 'v'; $variable->enum = array (array('Mars', 9.8), array('Earth', 3.77)); $variable->description; $variable->callback = 'callback_function';
//Add variable2
$variable = $variables[] = new stdClass;
$variable->name = 'var1'; $variable->generator = 'function'; $variable->value = 'v'; $variable->enum = array (array('Mars', 9.8), array('Earth', 3.77)); $variable->description; $variable->callback = 'callback_function';
```

At some point in the stdClass the developer has to specify where the variables should be placed. The placeholder template looks like this: `$variables[0]` which selects the first variable or `$variables[0][1]` which selects the first variable and then the first element in that variable. I hope that makes sense.

I have to come up with a php algorithm that go through a piece of text and replace all the placeholders with the correct values.

**My solution**

- Get all the variables->value into a new array. I have done this successfully.
- Get all the placeholders in a piece of text. I am stuck at this point. I don't use regular expressions much.
- I started by using:

  preg_match_all('/\$variables[[0-9a-zA-Z]+]/', $text, $matched_placeholders);

..but this will only match `$variables[0]` and I am tring to expand this to match variations such as: `$variables[0][1]` or `$variables[0][2][0]`, etc.

Once I have the placeholders into an array and the variables values into another array. I can do a `foreach` loop and replace all the placeholders.

Any advice will be appreciated. What regular expression pattern should I use to match this `$variables[0][2][0]`...

Answer (score 0):

Your `preg_match_all` function will look something like:

```
preg_match_all('/\$variables((\[[0-9a-zA-Z]+\])*)/', $text, $matched_placeholders);
```

This will match:

- `$variables`
- `$variables[#]`
- `$variables[#][#]`
- and so on

And will store the `[#][#][#]...` portion in `$matched_placeholders[1]`

Test with `$text = '$variables[0][1] or $variables[0][2][0]';`:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => $variables[0][1]
        [1] => $variables[0][2][0]
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => [0][1]
        [1] => [0][2][0]
    ) // The rest is just "noise"
    [2] => Array ( [0] => [1] [1] => [0] )
)
```

If, for example, you wanted to rename your variable (since I have no idea what you're actually trying to do but just helping you with the regex part), you could do:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\$variables((\[[0-9a-zA-Z]+\])*)/', '\$newvar$1', $text);
```

which would replace all occurences of `$variables` with `$newvar`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. You have really helped. Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

This will work :-

> > str.replaceAll( , );